# 401 error with Ajax JS button

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Seem to be having problems with a authentication on my Javascript buttons that are approving a comment. I have copied the code from a similar button system and changed it to match the requirements of this system.  Not sure if thats the issue? has anyone had similar?

Note: i get this whilst actually being logged in.

Here is my code, any ideas on why i'm getting the mismatch error?

```
   {error: "Unauthenticated."}
    error
    :
    "Unauthenticated."
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
         var urlApproval = '{{ route('approvals') }}';
        $('.approval').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var buttonToChange = $(this);
            var $this = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: urlApproval,
                        data: { comment_id: $(event.target).data("id")}
          })

                    .done(function() {
                        if(buttonToChange.hasClass('approved')) {
                            buttonToChange.addClass('not-approved');
                            buttonToChange.removeClass('approved');
                        }else {
                            buttonToChange.addClass('approved');
                            buttonToChange.removeClass('not-approved');
                        }
                    });
        });
```

Answered: Needed to define middleware on Controller/ Current middleware was blocking.

Comment: Is the route with the auth middleware? Maybe your are trying to access a "required auth route" without being authenticated.

Comment: Nice one for that you've just flicked the switch on for me. i havent defined the middleware for the function